# How can I recruit more high-level generals?

Tags: grand-battle

I really enjoy being a commander in Grand Battle. I feel quite excited especially when I subject the generals to my command. Any one can tell me how to recruit more high-level generals? The purple ones are great. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As for recruit generals, there are some good ways. You can go to [One in a Hundred] Recruit once every four hours and at most six times per day. [One in a Thousand] Recruit once everyday. [One in a Million] You have the opportunity to recruit a top-ranking general every three days, which means all of you can get blue ones at least. You will finally get the purple ones, and it’s just a matter of time. Of course, if you are not patient enough, you can resort to medals, and you are more likely to get the purple ones. I think it is very useful for all of the four characters of the generals, namely, courage(attack power), charm(crit rate), strategy(defense power) and control(hit point), so all of them should be brought average growth.